# Xamarin Android lock orientation in designer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, screen-orientation

I'm working on an app in Xamarin.Android and i need every screent to be in landscape. I managed to lock the orientation using `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape` in the activity flag in the back-end.
However the orientation remains at portrait in the designer. 
Does anyone know how i can fix that, because the layout I'm designing is only meant to work in Landscape orientation and it's a major pain working on the layout when the designer constantly flips me back to portrait.

EDIT: To point out, locking orientation works when I run the app, but not when I'm working on the front-end design (XML and designer)

Comment: Technically yes, but it messes up my workflow, it gets messed up and i feel like my markup is wrong.

Comment: Not to sound unprofessional, but that's just lame...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in Activity Flag

```
ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape
```

like following

```
 [Activity(Label = "my activity",ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape]
```

Comment: Like i said, that works, i was wondering if I could lock the designer in landscape, so nvm